# find the id of the next element present in next div-jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My form has number of input elements. When i looping through some elements i need to find the `id` of the next element which is in next div.

The whole code is in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95rqY/61/)

```
 $(":text[name^=sedan]").each(function(i){
var curTxtBox = $(this);
var curId = this.id;
alert(curId);   
    //var nextTextFieldId = $(this).closest('div').find('.number').attr("id");   // gives undefined
    var nextTextFieldId = $('#'+curId).next('div:input[type=text]').attr("id");   // gives undefined
   alert(nextTextFieldId ) 

});
```

this is not working. `nextTextFieldId` gives value undefined.

**html**

```
<div class="first">
    <div class="second">
       <input type="text" class ="myClass" name="sedan1" id = "sedan1"  value="1"  /> 
    </div>
    <div class="third">
       <input type="text" class ="yourClass" name="suv1" id ="suv1" value="2"/> 
   </div>
</div>
<div class="first">
  <div class="second">
      <input type="text" class ="myClass" name="sedan2" id = "sedan2"  value="3"  /> 
   </div>

   <div class="third">
    <input type="text" class ="yourClass" name="suv2" id = "suv2"  value="" />
  </div>        
</div>
```

Comment: Don't use `each` then. You already have all the elements you are looking for in the jQuery object, so simply do a `for` loop over them when you can access the "next" textbox with `results.get(i + 1)`. What you are doing here is making it more difficult for yourself.

Comment: Look at my answer below. You might want to modify it for your needs.

Answer (score 4):

```
var nextTextFieldId = $(this).parent().next().find(':text').attr("id");
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding my comment (*summary: don't do this, simply iterate over the jQuery object with `for` and be happy*) into an answer:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $textBoxes = $(":text[name^=sedan]");
    for(var i = 0; i < $textBoxes.length; ++i) {
        var $curTxtBox = $textBoxes.eq(i);
        alert($curTxtBox.attr("id"));
        if (i < $textBoxes.length - 1) {
            var nextTextBoxId = $textBoxes.eq(i + 1).attr("id");
            alert(nextTextBoxId);
        }
        else {
            // This was the last one, there is no "next" textbox
        }
    }
});
```

**Note that:**

1. Doing things this way does not require walking the DOM tree all the time like naive approaches using `each` (which end up searching the tree for the same element multiple times).
2. This approach will work correctly as long as you keep the `sedanXX` ids. Approaches that re-walk the DOM tree will break as soon as there is any significant change to your HTML.
3. If all you want is the id's, and they are incrementing integers, even this is overkill.

Comment: not looking like optimized one... Igors answer is works a treat!

Comment: @Hussain: I 'll just leave this "unoptimized" answer here because I suspect you might find it useful in the future. You 're welcome.

Comment: @Hussain: What exactly doesn't work? It works perfectly for me now, and it also worked before I posted this answer. Please read the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to this line:

```
var nextTextFieldId = $('#'+curId).parent().next('div:input[type=text]').attr("id");   // gives undefined
```

Your line expects the input tag to have a sibling div tag.

Comment: undefined... Igor Dymovs answer is perfect!

Comment: @Hussain: I hope you realize that Igor's answer will stop working the next time you change your HTML layout.